# Device orientation & pagination

Tags: php, javascript, css, ajax, mobile

I'm currently working on a mobile site that has tiles which represent each article. The pages have 15 tiles on them which is clean and works for both orientations on a mobile device. I recently added a featured article which takes up two space tiles worth of page space, so now I have one tile that is widowed on the bottom of the page.

Using some media queries I'm able to show/hide the last two tiles which works great until users click to the next page of tiles. If a user is in portrait orientation then they will miss two article tiles because they were hidden on the last page.

So I want to create some type of AJAX function that allows me to check the orientations and dynamically change the tile count request server side. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

[Jquery Mobile](http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/api/events.html) offers methods to look and know the orientation of the device.

Comment: But how would that help with the AJAX call?